# preg_match_all behaving weird on different servers

Tags: php, regex, linux, preg-match, match

I tried reading the other questions first but didn't find anything useful.

I have a development server with PHP 5.3.28 and PHP 5.4.7 on my own PC.

```
$string = '<if test="sub_function(parameter_1, parameter_2)">Match this</if>';
preg_match_all("/<if test=['\"]([!\w|&(),-\s]+)['\"]>(.*?)<\/if>/s", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The code above works fine on my xampp environment but doesn't work on the x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu server. The $matches is false on the linux environment and looks like this on my xampp:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Match this
            [1] => sub_function(parameter_1, parameter_2)
            [2] => Match this
        )
)
```

What could be causing this behaviour? This also works with my other PC with like PHP 5.2 - 5.3.

EDIT:
The regexp is deliberately complicated, it has more uses than the one I'm showing you. What I want to know is the things that affect preg_match behavior on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
[!\w|&(),-\s]
```

This is not a valid range. Some PCRE versions are more permissive and allow stuff like that, but (at least, on OSX), php 5.5 and 5.6 refuse to run this saying that

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 25...
```

You can easily fix that by escaping `-` or moving it to the end:

```
[!\w|&(),\-\s]
```

Also, it's always helpful to set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`.

Comment: I think OP meant to use it as `-` char itself

Comment: This was the correct answer (I will accept it a bit later). Could you escape why I have to escape - sign? What does - represent in regexp?

Comment: @unska: `-` is special inside `[]`'s - it represents ranges. For example, `[a-z]` = from a to z.